Git clone hangs at `git-lfs: filepathfilter`
I'm git clone a model repo which contains large file to be downloaded by lfs.
The command I used is:
git lfs install
env GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1  clone https://huggingface.co/mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2
I found that the clone progress just hangs at trace git-lfs: xfer: adapter "basic" worker 2 finished job for "fdsfdsfdsafdsafdasfdsafdasfdsa" trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "tokenizer.model" without ending.
Any comment is welcomed, thx.

I tried to download lfs in two phases, and can saw the lfs download in progress that way.
download binary files later by skip-smudge
git lfs install --skip-smudge
// Do git clone here
git clone xxx 
// Fetch all the binary files in the new clone
cd xxx
git lfs pull 
// Reinstate smudge 
git lfs install --force

Leave thread here for anyone who might run into the same issue. And welcome more direct answers to the question.
